# HttpServletResponse: Keep, Save or Persist the response for later use...?

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, openid

I am using Spring to create my webapp. I have a scenario like:

An `ExternalService` sends a `GET` request to my `Controller` that has a mapping `/DoOperation` with some user info as param. I get the param check the user if he is logged into my system or not if NOT i send him to `OpenId` verification with `returnUrl`, which is in same webapp say `/Authenticated`.

The ExternalService does not provide a `returnUrl` (Not related to `OpenId` returnUrl) and forces to respond the same request it made at `/DoOperation`.

Now, How could I keep the very `HttpServletResponse` (if there is a way, apparently there is not) so that I can write a response once I have gone somewhere else e.g. at `OpenID` page to verify user and then `/Authenticate` in this case... so that `ExternalService` could read it.

Could Servlet Filter help here?

Comment: I do not believe you can keep the same HttpServletResponse accross requests.  Its not how Servlets work.  What you will have to do is use some async requests to do what you need.  I am not sure why you would want to perform /DoOperation without an authenticated user first, though.  Seems a little unsecure.

Comment: Ya iknow. but i was wandering if there is a way to do so... actually the webapp further connects to Domino and that needs the domino user session to do operations, otherwise it would be insecure.. thx anyway

Comment: The way to do this would be to split the process into two parts.  Part one is a request to /DoOperation.  Part two would be to something to get the results from DoOperation.  Then you could start the process, and get the results asynchronously.  But, my comment about it being unsecured was that it seems like you are allowing anyone to start /DoOperation prior to getting authenticated.  If this is the case, what is stopping someone from DoS'ing your application by calling /DoOperation over and over without ever really authenticating?

Comment: Sorry overlooked that part of the comment. The webapp+Domino stuff is hidden from user in a way that User is being served by ExternalService for everything, and ExternalService can't send credentials to verify him on our system. ExternalService is acting like a field hospital but getting the contents from the webapp... user will be authed for ExternalService not for us... and i wanted  it to be authed for us as well...

Comment: I would look into doing a SSO solution before I tried to do some OAuth hack.  If this is truly a service call, then there should be no reason that the client of the call couldn't send the credentials along with the request.

Comment: Have you looked at Spring Security for your authentication needs? Apart from all the hard implementation stuff it also offers battle proofed design patterns as how to tackle web security in Java